# How to handle this scenario in single SSIS package?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis-2012

I'm receiving around 100 `excel` files on daily basis ,in these 100 files there are 4 types of files which name start with (**ALC,PLC,GLC** and **SLC**) and then some random No. and each `excel` file `sheetname` is same as filename.

Now inside of each type and each file at cell A3 there is 'request by' and then user name for **eg-Request by 'Ajeet'** and we want to pick the file which is requested by only 'Ajeet', first few rows are not formatted, actual data start from.

```
ALC data start from A33 Cell
PLC data start from A36 Cell
GLC data start from A32 cell
SLC data start from A38 cell
```

And few files having no data so in that case "NoData" is mentioned in respective type of files from where data start.

All type of file containing same no. of column.

So how can we handle all these situation in `SSIS` and load the data into a single SQL table but without using script task. I have attached snapshot one of the file for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help. 
[how-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file-starting-from-the-nth-row-with-sql-server-integration-services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4150/how-to-read-data-from-an-excel-file-starting-from-the-nth-row-with-sql-server-integration-services/)

Copying the solution here in case the link is unavailable

***Solution 1 - Using the OpenRowset Function***

[image: right click on the Excel Source and select Properties]

[image: modify the OpenRowset property]

***Solution 2 - Query Excel Sheet***

[image: Edit the connection manager and change the data access mode to SQL Command]

***Solution 3 - Google It***

Google it, The information above is from the first search result

Comment: I appreciates and  thanks for your efforts ,this will solve only the purpose of reading either requested by column or data form where it is starting in a single files but what will be the logic if the file name is changing and sheet name is also changing ,I'm looking for that logic ,if you know please let me know

Comment: Variables and a loop. [how-to-loop-through-files-in-a-specified-folder-load-one-by-one](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/how-to-loop-through-files-in-a-specified-folder-load-one-by-one-and-move-to-archive-folder-using-ssis). Was the first search result

Comment: thanks bro ,try to build package using all the suggestion